# Cannot call functions in a DLL

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, msbuild, shared-libraries

So I want to make a shared library, and testing how it works... But I just don't understand what am I doing wrong here...

main.cpp:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>

__declspec(dllimport) int foo(int);

int main() {
    std::cout << foo(5) << std::endl;
}
```

shared.cpp:

```
shared.cpp
__declspec(dllexport) int foo(int k) {
    return k;
}
```

Every time I tried to build, it fails with the following output:
output:

```
[build] MSBuild version 17.7.2+d6990bcfa for .NET Framework
[build] 
[build]   MnShared.vcxproj -> D:\Programs\tst\mn\build\Debug\MnShared.dll
[build]   main.cpp
[build] main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl foo(int)" (__imp_?foo@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function main
[build] D:\Programs\tst\mn\build\Debug\MN.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
[proc] The command: "E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build d:/Programs/tst/mn/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -j 10 -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:02.045
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

NOTE: shared.cpp and main.cpp are in the same project and are getting built in the same directory

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(MN CXX)

add_executable(MN main.cpp)

add_library(MnShared SHARED shared.cpp)
```

Comment: Can you show how the import library for the dll is being linked to the executable?

Comment: Don't tag C++ code as C.

Comment: ***E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"*** Show your `CMakeLists.txt` This is likely where your bug is.

Comment: @RetiredNinja shouldn't the dll get linked at runtime by some WINAPI thing? if no, and i am missing something, please correct me.

Comment: No msvc does not link to dlls in standard c++. You need to link to the `.lib` file created with your dll. This `.lib` file is not a static library its an import library. It contains only stubbs to the functions that are implemented in the dll you created.

Comment: @drescherjm then how to tell the loader to load some `abc.dll` ?

Comment: You need to add `target_link_libraries( MN PRIVATE MnShared)` at the bottom of your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: ***then how to tell the loader to load some dll*** linking to the import library does this for you.

Comment: @drescherjm well thanks... it works... I assumed `target_link_libraries()` was only for static libraries..... apparently not. Again, thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `target_link_libraries(MN PRIVATE MnShared)` at the bottom of `CMakeLists.txt` solved the problem.